# Get nullable bool value by JSON in swift. Cast AnyObject? to Bool

Tags: json, swift, web-services

I have a web-service which gets its data from SQL Server 2014.
There is a gender column in the database table which is nullable.

Return data is JSON.

My problem is in my iOS App I have to know when it's null as well
I tried:

```
let gender: Bool? = json["gender"] as! Bool?
```

But in the following code the `gender == false` is executed:

```
if gender == true {
   self.genderSelection.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
} else if gender == false {
   self.genderSelection.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
}
```

And gender != nil is always true (I couldn't use that)

JSON return value is one of the following:

- {"gender": true}
- {"gender": false}
- {"gender": null}

I want the whole if statement to be ignored if the gender is null in the SQL Server Database.

P.S.: Database and web-service are not mine and I can't change the return datatype/value nor change the gender column datatype.

P.P.S.: json["gender"] datatype is AnyObject?. This is obvious but doesn't hurt to mention.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've found that, JSON puts false to any values which are not equal "true".
To be able to have 3 options (in this case) web-service must return something other that bool, like string or integer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will only be run if **json["gender"]** returns anything other then nil. In your case its true or false.

```
if let gender = json["gender"] as! Bool{
   if gender == true {
     self.genderSelection.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
   } else if gender == false {
     self.genderSelection.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
   }
}
```

Comment: gender == true and gender == false says "Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject?' to expected argument type 'Bool'"

Comment: no, null answer from server cause the false statement to run. :| After your first answer I tried this but just in case I copied your new answer and tried again.

Comment: can you print the value of gender print(gender) and see what does it hold

Comment: It says Optional(false). I tried let gender: Bool? = json["gender"] as! Bool? and let gender: Bool? = json["gender"] as? Bool

Comment: I have tried everything. It looks like JSON returns false for anything other than true. Have to ask the server administrator to edit the web-service (if possible).